# Best option to store long lists of data in android

Tags: java, android, xml

Im writing an app for fellow students at my university to make using the public transit a bit easier.

It is a xml parser that grabs the times the next bus is going to stop at your current busstop. Which online its laid out as 
    Choose bus > 06-Richmond
    Choose direction > south
    Choose stop > 141

then i will use a string builder to create the extension `ada.aspx?r=06&d=3&s=141` to parse the information.

My problem is, there are around 2000 entries that need to be stored, and to make it more efficient I read I should use XML, but how do i associate 06-Richmond so that when the user clicks it it stores 06 in a variable. 
I have them stored in a XML string array as of now.

`

```
<string-array name="bus_routes">

    <item>01 Kipps Lane / Thompson Road</item>
    <item>02 Dundas st</item>
    <item>03 Hailton Rd</item>
    <item>04 Oxford East</item>
    <item>05 Springbank</item>
    <item>06 Richmond</item>
    <item>07 Wavell</item>
    <item>08 Riverside</item>
    <item>09 Whitehills </item>
    <item>10 Wonderland</item>`
```

Should i be using a different method for storage, my hopes is so that when you click Richmond the ID tag is 06 or something like the sort. I bought the Apress book to learn, and its not doing the job, so if anyone has any books they think are good reads as well, that would be quite nice as well.

Thanks

Comment: why are you not using SQLite database available?

Comment: I have noooooo experience with SQLite, so i went with XML because i knew it more, but i shall go and learn, because this seems like the wya to go

I am also new and didnt know i could use SQLite.

Comment: i have added the link you can check it out.. should be helpful for you to implement SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either change the storage method (to like, database) or if you keep the XML method then create yourself a method that will return the string/or the number something like:

```
public int getBusIndex(String myButtonText)
{
String[] bus = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.bus_routes);
    for(String s: bas)
    {
     if(s.contains(myButtonText))   //simple linear search
         return Integer.parseInt(s);
    }

return -1;// if the search is not successfull (also try to implement more faster searches, see Collections class)
}
```

and you call:

`int busIndex = getBusIndex(mButton.getText()); // supposing we are dealing with button`

But if you also plan to write (dynamically new stuffs in your strings array (xml) you definitely need to change the method.

`My personal opinion and choice:
Writing simple query against database will cut on memory resources for loading all the string entries. Since you will have ID column (of integer type) which will do the work of`06`stuff.`

Comment: I should have added, the get bus ID with the string array does work past route 22, because it jumps for 22 to 25, so the string IDs are off by 3, which is why i wanted a manual way to set them.

So a Sqldatabase your saying is the best? Time to learn SQL :D

Comment: I did not understand your problem (maybe misunderstood it). So you want to store something like 06-Tony and then 09-Nikola ? or you want to go from something at 06 to 09?

Comment: Like from what i know, android stores the ID in order 0 to N, so when i grab the ID of bus 01-KippsLane, the ID is 0, and the route 2 Dundas, the ID is 01, so i cant tell the program to grab the ID and store the ID as my R value for the string builder, I need a way, that i can store the Route 02-Dundas, with a value of 02 assoicated with it. 

The same for when i have to add all the bustops like "Alumini Hall" has a value of 141.

Comment: Use `Map<Integer, String>;` `Integer`object will hold the 02 and the String will hold the Dundas. If you are not familiar with `Integer` class make sure that this is different from `int` primitive type. If you are not familiar with `Map<?,?>` class, look around for usage examples (no books needed, I promise)

`Integer` will be the key to which `String` will be associated.